# General expression of the exponential function of a matrix

Tags: matrices, jordan-normal-form, block-matrices

For matrix $A \in \mathbb{C}^{n\times n},$ it is well-known that there exists an invertible $P$ so that $PA=JP,$ where $J$ is the Jordan canonical form of $A$. Hence we have $e^A=P^{-1}e^JP.$ For real parameter $t$, if we want to compute $e^{tA},$ we could first compute the matrix $J=\text{diag}\{J_1,\cdots,J_k\},$ where
$$
J_i=\begin{pmatrix} \lambda_i & 1 & \\ & \lambda_i & 1 & \\ & & \ddots & \ddots & \\ & & & \lambda_i & 1 \\ & & & & \lambda_i  \end{pmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^{n_i \times n_i},
$$
Then
$$
e^{tJ_i}=e^{\lambda_i }\begin{pmatrix} 1 & t & \frac{t^2}{2} & \cdots & \frac{t^{n_i-1}}{(n_i-1)!} \\ & 1 & t & \cdots & \frac{t^{n_i-2}}{(n_i-2)!}\\ & & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots & \\ & & & 1 & t \\ & & & & 1  \end{pmatrix}.
$$
Therefore $e^{tA}=P^{-1}\text{diag}\{e^{tJ_1},\cdots,e^{tJ_k}\}P.$

Recently I have read a more abstract but general way in a paper to express $e^{tA}.$ With the notations as we stated above, the paper said that (without any explanation)
$$
e^{tA}=\sum_{i=1}^k \sum_{l=0}^{n_k-1}  e^{t\lambda_i}t^l Z_{il},
$$
where $Z_{il}(i=1,\cdots,k;l=1,\cdots,n_k)$ are certain linearly independent matrices. How to deduce the above expression?

Motivated by @RobertIsrael 's answer, we should find polynomials $P_{il}$ for $1\leq i \leq k, 0 \leq l \leq n_k-1$ so that

$$
\frac{d^p}{dx^p}e^{tx}|_{x=\lambda}=\sum_{i=1}^k \sum_{l=0}^{n_i-1}  e^{t\lambda_i}t^l P_{il}(\lambda)
$$

for $\lambda=\lambda_1,\cdots,\lambda_k,p=0,\cdots,n_i-1,i=1,\cdots,k.$

The difficult is $\lambda_1$ could be equal to $\lambda_2$ since the diagonal elements for two Jordan blocks can coincide. Let us consider a simple case, assume $k=2$, i.e there are two Jordan blocks, and $\lambda_1=\lambda_2.$ We also assume the order of the two blocks are $n_1=2$ and $n_2=2$ respectively.

Since $e^{t\lambda_1}t^l=\frac{d^l}{dx^l}e^{tx}|_{x=\lambda_1},$ we should choose the polynominal so that

$$P_{10}(\lambda_1)+P_{20}(\lambda_1)=1,$$

$$P_{11}(\lambda_1)+P_{21}(\lambda_1)=0,$$

$$P_{10}^{'}(\lambda_1)+P_{20}^{'}(\lambda_1)=0,$$

$$P_{11}^{'}(\lambda_1)+P_{21}^{'}(\lambda_1)=1.$$

When I found these polynomials, how to show that
$$
P_{il}(A), \quad i=1,2, l=1,2
$$
are linearly independent?

Comment: One way to do it is to write the Taylor series expansion of the exponential function $e^x$, then replace $x$ with the matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look up: Holomorphic functional calculus. More generally, if $f$ is any function analytic in a neighbourhood of $\sigma(A)$ (the set of eigenvalues of $A$), then $f(A) = p(A)$ where $p(z)$ is a polynomial of degree $\le n$ such that, for each eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $A$ with (algebraic) multiplicity $m(\lambda)$,
$p^{(k)}(\lambda) = f^{(k)}(\lambda)$ for $0 \le k \le m(\lambda)-1$.  This lets you write
$$ f(A) = \sum_{\lambda \in \sigma(A)} \sum_{k=0}^{m(\lambda)} f^{(k)}(\lambda) Z_{\lambda,k}(A)$$
where $Z_{\lambda,k}(z)$ is a polynomial such that $Z_{\lambda,k}^{(k)}(\lambda) = 1$, $Z_{\lambda,k}^{(j)}(\lambda) = 0$ for all other $j \in \{0,\ldots,m(\lambda)\}$,
and $Z_{\lambda,k}^{(j)}(\mu) = 0$ for $0 \le j \le m(\mu)$ where $\mu \ne \lambda$ is another eigenvalue of $A$.

[EDIT] Note that each $\lambda$ is listed once here.  In your example, with with two Jordan blocks of order $2$ but only one $\lambda$, we want
$Z_{\lambda,0}(\lambda) = 1$, $Z'_{\lambda,0}(\lambda) = 0$ and
$Z_{\lambda,1}(\lambda) = 0$, $Z'_{\lambda,1}(\lambda) = 1$: we can take
$Z_{\lambda_0}(z) = 1$ and $Z_{\lambda,1}(z) = z-\lambda$.  The result is
$$ f(A) = f(\lambda) I + f'(\lambda) (A-\lambda I)$$

Comment: Thank you for your beautiful answer. I have looked up and read the Dunford-Taylor formula. However, in your expression the $m(\lambda)$ is the algebraic multiplicity, while the $n_k$ in my expression stands for the order of each Jordan block. The sum of all of the orders of Jordan block of one eigenvalue is the algebraic multiplicity. Do the two expressions coincide?

Comment: Actually you can take $m(\lambda)$ to be the order of the largest Jordan block for eigenvalue $\lambda$, since $Z_{\lambda,k}(A)$ will be $0$ for $k$ greater than that.

Comment: When I rewrite your answer, I still find some difficulties. I have edited my question for elaborating. Could you help me again?